# res.status is not a function Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, testing, puppeteer

I'm trying to get the status code of a page.goto in Puppeteer:

```
describe('score', () => {
  test('correct flag should return 200', async() => {
    const url = 'localhost:8080';

    const res = page.goto(url, {
      waitUntil: 'networkidle2'
    });
    expect(res.status()).toEqual(200);
  });
});
```

However, I keep getting `TypeError: res.status is not a function`. I've also tried res.ok() but got the same thing. Any ideas?

Comment: `const res = await page.goto(` maybe?

Answer (score 1):

```
describe('score', () => {
  test('correct flag should return 200', async() => {
    const url = 'localhost:8080';

    const res = await page.goto(url, {
      waitUntil: 'networkidle2'
    });
    expect(res.status()).toEqual(200);
  });
});
```

your problem is that you are tying to do apply methode from a promise and not from 'data'with the await operator you are waiting until the promise resolve and then res will be some data and not a Promise object